# How to get the sum of rows then get the average of the calculate sum

Tags: sqlite

I have a database that represent music shop data.
Tables I want to work with are (artist, album, track)
every album has an albumID, title and artistID
and every track has TrackID, Milliseconds, albumID and name

well, as you know every album has many tracks
I want to calculate the sum of all songs in the album(in Milliseconds) Then get the average of that sum to get the albums that are above the average in length.

I managed to calculate the length of every album but i struggled to get the average.

I want to generate a table that will be like that.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
AlbumID  |  Tile  |  Milliseconds
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1-       |        |
2-       |        |
3-       |        |
...
10-      |        |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Sample table of Track

```
TrackID  |      Name        | AlbumId | Milliseconds
1   For Those About To Rock      1         343719
6   Put The Finger On You        1         205662
7   Let's Get It Up              1         233926
85  Cochise                      10        222380
86  Show Me How to Live          10        277890
87  Gasoline                     10        279457
88  What You Are                 10        249391
89  Like a Stone                 10        294034
99  Your Time Has Come           11        255529
100 Out Of Exile                 11        291291
101 Be Yourself                  11        279484
102 Doesn't Remind Me            11        255869
111 Money                        12        147591
112 Long Tall Sally              12        106396
```

so, LIMIT 10
and the length of the track

Comment: Use `avg()`? If that's not enough, show a sample table (As create table/insert statements so it can easily be copy and pasted) and your desired results.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at aggregate functions? We're not doing your homework for you.  What database are you using? What is 'Tile'? Which limit of 10 do you want?

Comment: guys avg() function is not working on milliseconds directly like that `avg(t.milliseconds)`. because on the Track table, I have many tracks with the same albumID, So i have to sum them first.

Comment: @danblack I have tried 
```
SELECT al.AlbumId, al.Title, sum(t.milliseconds) as allsum
FROM Album al
JOIN Track t on al.AlbumId=t.AlbumId
GROUP by al.AlbumId
HAVING allsum >= avg(allsum)
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: @danblack also thisSelect al. avg(TotalAlbumLength)
FROM (
  SELECT t.AlbumId, sum(t.Milliseconds) as TotalAlbumLength
  FROM Track t
  )
  JOIN Album al on t.AlbumId=al.AlbumId
  GROUP by al.AlbumId

Comment: @danblack title mean the title of the album(name of the album), limit 10 mean i want the top 10 longest albums

Comment: You either want 10 top albums in length, or albums that are above the average length - not both.

Comment: use `avg` over `derived summarized table`

Comment: MySQL <> SQLite, i suggest you edit the question and tag only the database system your are using if you are looking for a query which works in both SQLite and MySQL you can ideally remove both tags as the `sql` tag is for cross database platform queries more or less as the tag is meant for ANSI/ISO valid SQL queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the following may be what you wish :-

```
WITH albumsums(id,asum) AS (
    SELECT albumid, sum(milliseconds) 
    FROM track 
    GROUP BY albumid
)
SELECT album.albumid, album.title, asum 
FROM album 
JOIN albumsums 
    ON album.albumid = albumsums.id  
WHERE asum > (SELECT avg(asum) FROM albumsums)
LIMIT 10;
```

Consider the following demo :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS track;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS artist;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS album;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS track (trackid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, milliseconds INTEGER, albumid);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS artist (artistid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, artistname TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS album (albumid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, artistid INTEGER);
INSERT INTO artist (artistname) VALUES ('Pink Floyd'),('Genesis'),('Deep Purple');
INSERT INTO album (title,artistid) VALUES('Dark side of the moon',1),('Fireball',3),('Foxtrot',2);
INSERT INTO track (name,milliseconds,albumid) VALUES
    ('Supper''s Ready',((22 * 60) + 57) * 1000,3),
    ('Watcher of the Skies',((7 * 60) + 21) + 1000,3),
    ('Time Table',((4 * 60) + 47) * 1000,3),
    ('Get ''Em Out by Friday',((8 * 60) + 35) * 1000,3),
    ('Can-Utility and the Coastliners',((5 * 60) + 45 ) * 1000,3),
    ('Speak to me /Breath',((3 * 60) + 58) * 1000,1),
    ('On the Run',((3 * 60) + 35) * 1000,1),
    ('Time',((7 * 60) + 5) * 1000,1),
    ('The Great Gig in the Sky',((4 * 60) + 44) * 1000,1),
    ('Money',((6 * 60) + 23) * 1000,1),
    ('Use and Them',((7 * 60) + 50) * 1000,1),
    ('Any Colour you Like',((3 * 60) + 26) * 1000,1),
    ('Brain Damage',((3 * 60) + 47) * 1000,1),
    ('Fireball',((3 * 60) + 24) * 1000,2),
    ('No No No',((6 * 60) + 54) * 1000,2),
    ('Demon''s Eye',((5 * 60) + 21) * 1000,2),
    ('Anyone''s Daughter',((4 * 60) + 43) * 1000,2),
    ('The Mule',((5 * 60) + 21) * 1000,2),
    ('Fools',((8 * 60) + 19) * 1000,2),
    ('No One Came',((6 * 60) + 34) * 1000,1),
    ('Strange Kind of Woman',((4 * 60) + 07) * 1000,1)
;
SELECT * FROM artist;
SELECT * FROM album;
SELECT * FROM track;

SELECT albumid, sum(milliseconds) 
    FROM track 
    GROUP BY albumid
;

WITH albumsums(id,asum) AS (
    SELECT albumid, sum(milliseconds) 
    FROM track 
    GROUP BY albumid
)
SELECT album.albumid, album.title, asum, (SELECT avg(asum) FROM albumsums AS album_average_for_demo)
FROM album 
JOIN albumsums 
    ON album.albumid = albumsums.id  
WHERE asum > (SELECT avg(asum) FROM albumsums);
```

The net result (as you wanted above average) being just one album above the average :-

[image]

The CTE (Common Table Expression albumsums) as demonstrated by the previous query produces 3 rows (1 per album) with the album id and the sum of the tracks :-

[image]

Thus the average album length is 2552147 and thus only 1 album is greater than that (as would be expected from such a limited amount of data).

The tables (after being loaded) being :-

[image]
[image]
[image]